# Cloud Formation in auto scaling using aws sdk command line

Tags: amazon-ec2, scalability, aws-cloudformation

I am using aws sdk for [auto scaling command line tool](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/). I want to know that how to use cloud formation with this command line tool? i.e. can we give template id instead of instance/ ami id?

Example:

```
as-create-launch-config MyLC --image-id <CF tamplete id> --instance-type m1.small
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can we give template id instead of instance/ ami id?

No, using [Auto Scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) with [AWS CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) currently works the other way round only:

- [AWS CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) fully supports all *Auto Scaling* resources like [AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html), [AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html) etc., see the [AWS Resource Types Reference](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html) for details on all available resources; there are a couple of *Auto Scaling* related [AWS CloudFormation Sample Templates](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/) to get you started as well:

  - [AutoScalingKeepAtNSample.template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/AutoScalingMultiAZSample.template) - *An example of using Auto Scaling groups to manage a set of EC2 instances.*
  - [AutoScalingMultiAZSample.template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/AutoScalingMultiAZSample.template) - *An example of using Load Balanced, Auto Scaling groups spanning multiple EC2 availability zones. This template has been updated to use Auto Scaling Policies.*
  - [AutoScalingMultiAZWithNotifications.template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/AutoScalingMultiAZWithNotifications.template) - *An example of using Load Balanced Auto Scaling groups spanning multiple EC2 availability zones. This template uses Auto Scaling Policies and configures Auto Scaling notifications so that you can get emails when scaling events occur.*
- You can then use the [AWS CloudFormation Command Line Tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2555753788650372) to use your template(s) with said *Auto Scaling* resources, e.g. via [cfn-create-stack](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-stack.html), [cfn-update-stack](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/update-stack.html) etc., see the [Command Line Tools Reference](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/CFN_CMD.html) for details on all available commands.